# jquery resizable: dynamic minHeight

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-resizable

How can I have a dynamic `minHeight`, that is based on the inner container? I have:

```
<div id="outer-div" >
    <div id="inner-div"></div>
</div>
```

Then on jQuery:

```
$( "#outer-div" ).resizable({
    containment: "#another-outer-div",
    minWidth: 200,
    minHeight: $('#inner-div').height(),
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        ui.size.width += (ui.size.width - ui.originalSize.width);
        $(this).position({
            of: $("#another-outer-div"),
            my: "center center",
            at: "center center"
        })
    }
});
```

The `minHeight` above is not working, but hope you get the idea of what I want to do; the height of the resizeable `div` should not be smaller than the inner `div`, which has the content.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you search for:

```
$("#outer-div").resizable({
    containment: "#another-outer-div",
    minWidth: 200,
    start: function(event,ui) {
        $("#outer-div").css({
            minHeight: $('#inner-div').outerHeight()
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is rather old, but during initialization, you can only assign an integer to minHeight and minWidth. You can't use a query. The correct way is to modify the minHeight or minWidth Option in the "start"-Handler like so:

```
$( "#outer-div" ).resizable({
    containment: "#another-outer-div",
    minWidth: 200,
    minHeight: $('#inner-div').height(),
    start: function(event,ui) {
        var myMinHeight = $('#inner-div').height();
        $( "#outer-div" ).resizable( "option", "minHeight", myMinHeight );
    },
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        ui.size.width += (ui.size.width - ui.originalSize.width);
        $(this).position({
            of: $("#another-outer-div"),
            my: "center center",
            at: "center center"
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Should the option there be minHeight rather than minWidth.
`$( "#outer-div" ).resizable( "option", "minHeight", myMinHeight );`

Comment: Yep. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 0):

I've never messed with ui-resizable but here's how I set my min-height so content stretches to the bottom.

```
adjustedHeight = (the equation for min-height);
$(".stretchClass").css({'min-height':(adjustedHeight+'px')})
```